# How To limit Nginx Auth_Basic re-tries?

Tags: security, nginx

I have protected a web folder with Nginx's Auth_Basic module. The problem is, we can try several passwords until it works (brute force attacks). Is there a way to limit the number of failed re-tries?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As far as I know, [Auth Basic](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule) module doesn't support this feature, but you can do this by using [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Testing with a non-existent user, you will see something like belows in the error log:

`2012/08/25 10:07:01 [error] 5866#0: *1 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /pma HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:81"
2012/08/25 10:07:04 [error] 5866#0: *1 user "ajfkla" was not found in "/etc/nginx/htpasswd", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /pma HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:81"`

Then create necessary filter:

**`/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-auth.conf`**

```
[Definition]
failregex = no user/password was provided for basic authentication.*client: <HOST>
              user .* was not found in.*client: <HOST>
              user .* password mismatch.*client: <HOST>
ignoreregex = </host></host></host>
```

**`/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`**

```
[nginx-auth]
enabled = true
filter = nginx-auth
action = iptables[name=NoAuthFailures, port=80, protocol=tcp]
logpath = /var/log/nginx*/*error*.log
bantime = 3600 # 1 hour
maxretry = 3
```

Testing Fail2Ban rules:

**`fail2ban-regex /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-auth.conf`**

```
Failregex
|- Regular expressions:
|  [1] no user/password was provided for basic authentication.*client: <HOST>
|  [2] user .* was not found in.*client: <HOST>
|  [3] user .* password mismatch.*client: <HOST>
|
`- Number of matches:
   [1] 1 match(es)
   [2] 2 match(es)
   [3] 0 match(es)

Ignoreregex
|- Regular expressions:
|
`- Number of matches:

Summary
=======

Addresses found:
[1]
    127.0.0.1 (Sat Aug 25 10:07:01 2012)
[2]
    127.0.0.1 (Sat Aug 25 10:07:04 2012)
    127.0.0.1 (Sat Aug 25 10:07:07 2012)
[3]
```

PS: Since Fail2ban fetches log files to ban, make sure `logpath` matches with your configuration.

Answer (score 10):

I'm amazed no on else has given this solution/workaround.

Nginx basic-auth and `htpasswd` support bcrypt password encryption with an optional cost variable. Bcrypt is designed to be slow, thus providing a hard limit on how fast you can attempt different passwords.

When creating your basic auth username/password use

```
htpasswd -B -C 12 path/to/users.db <username>
```

With a cost of 12 your server will likely not be able to try passwords more than a few times a second, increase that to say 14 and you'll probably be looking at around 1s per password attempt.

With that configured any reasonable password will be immune to brute force attack even if the attacker tried passwords continuously for years.

E.g. at 10 password attempts per second brute force attack on an 8 character alphanumeric password would take 692,351 years: `62**8 / (10*3600*24*365)`.

This is much easier to configure and more fool-proof than setting up "intelligent" request limitting.

Comment: This would be useful if you could use `bcrypt`ed passwords with Nginx's basic auth, but apparently [you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35834603/100339).

Comment: I've tried it, it works absolutely fine for me. Using it in production now.

Comment: Not working on vanilla ngix on ubuntu as @keune said

Comment: Worth mentioning that this will limit password attempts, but only because your server will be overloaded from computing expensive hashes. In a production environment, this isn't probably what you want.

Comment: Robust and easy, yes. Allows DoS attacks against CPU usage.

Comment: HTTP basic auth is cached on the browser/client and credentials are sent with every HTTP request. Thus, I assume the slow password check will happen not only when the user enters the password, but also afterwards during browsing, which results in slower response and bad UX. Plus, others already pointed out: your server is constantly busy computing hashes, wasting energy, resources, money. Not really an optimal solution.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe nginx has any internal facility to do this.  The [documentation page](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule) doesn't suggest it's possible.

You can use Fail2Ban to block IP addresses that have repeated failed login attempts.

The Fail2Ban wiki has some [nginx-specific patterns](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/NginX).

Fail2Ban should be available as a package on most of the big distros.

Answer (score 2):

[Nginx-HTTP-Auth-Digest](https://github.com/samizdatco/nginx-http-auth-digest) module can replace the basic auth module with many additional feature suck as retry and timeout. Additional documentation is available [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/auth_digest/)

The only downside is that this probably require rebuilding nginx

Answer (score 1):

This can be acomplished with a combination of NGINX basic auth and rate limiting.

```
http {
    map $http_cookie $rate_limit_key {
        default $binary_remote_addr;
        "~__Secure-rl-bypass=SomeRandomBytes" "";
    }
    limit_req_status 429;
    limit_req_zone $rate_limit_key zone=auth:10m rate=1r/m;

    server {
            auth_basic "Private Content";
            auth_basic_user_file your-auth-file.txt;

            limit_req zone=auth burst=20 delay=10;

            add_header Set-Cookie "__Secure-rl-bypass=SomeRandomBytes;Max-Age=${toString (3600*24*180)};Domain=$host;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly";
    }
}
```

This snippet was extracted from my working config, but the snippet itself wasn't tested.

The basic concept is that you create a cookie that allows bypassing the rate limit then set the cookie once someone successfully authenticates. This way someone is rate-limited until they login at which point they can perform as many requests as they want.

The major downside to this approach is that the cookie is static, once someone is logged in on any account they can use the token to brute force other accounts. This is not a major issue if your users are trusted not to brute force the password of other users. However I don't think you can do better than this in NGINX's config. Ideally the cookie would be `hash("$remote_user-SomeRandomBytes")` so that the token is bound to the user that successfully logged in.

Comment: I came here looking for a way to protect a single-user application on a shared system where I can't use fail2ban, and this seems perfect for that. Definitely a hack, though.

Answer (score 1):

### DO NOT USE THIS.

**As pointed out in the comments: THIS IS NOT A CORRECT SOLUTION!**
...but why? Because this only limits the Nginx-Response for Authentication-Failed. The credentials will be processed regardless, and any success may lead to the proper 200-OK response. Any attacker may perceive this as a "proper" rate-limit solution, but can still try to authenticate further!

*Original post:*

Just to chime in my own solution to this problem: It is based on an other (popular) answer, similar to your problem. Here is the configuration:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=login:10m rate=10r/m;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name XXX;

    location / {
        auth_basic "Authentication required.";
        auth_basic_user_file /path/to/htpasswd; # You should change this
        error_page 401 /AuthFailureLimit/index.html;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/normal; # Demo
    }

    location /AuthFailureLimit {
        internal; # To prevent visible redirects
        auth_basic off; # Just in case the "auth_basic" was used in the "server" section

        limit_req zone=login burst=20 nodelay;
        limit_req_log_level warn; # Show blocks on the console
        limit_req_status 429; # Make more sense than "503 Service Unavailable"
        
        # ONLY use root or alias in this location, other statements (like return) will be executed before the rate limit triggers!
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/ratelimit; # Demo
    }
}
```

It allows you to directly utilize the rate limiting feature of NGINX, without requiring the client to store e.g. cookies. Please note the comments in the configuration itself, as (due to the different NGINX phases) some statements may mess up the rate limits.

Comment: Doesn't this rate-limit the _401 error page_ rather than the actual authentication ie: I could still brute-force happily, I just might not see the 401 responses? But I appreciate nginx processing isn't obvious...

Comment: Thank you very much - this is very much correct. What a mistake...