# Nginx how to use limit_req_zone on auth_basic to protect against brute force attack?

Tags: nginx, http-basic-authentication, brute-force-attacks

I have an Nginx server that works as an SSL proxy for a service running on a localhost that doesn't support SSL authentication.

I would like to use Nginx's [limit_req_zone](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req_zone) function to protect the Basic_Auth against brute force attacks. There is a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/421046/how-to-limit-nginx-auth-basic-re-tries) with the answer to use Fail2ban, but I would like to use limit_req_zone if possible.

I've got it working - It is done using these two lines of code:

```
http {
  limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=30r/m; # only one login in 2 seconds allowed
  ...

  location / {
    limit_req zone=one burst=5 nodelay; # only five connections allowed for the whole / root
    ...
    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:2222/myapp/www/; # redirections to my unauthenticated service
  }
}
```

The problem is **it also blocks number of requests when user is authenticated** which results in fact, that `http://127.0.0.1:2222/myapp/www/` is not fully loaded.

What `location` directive should I use to block only number of attempts to use Basic_Auth?

Comment: Now you know why you were recommended to use fail2ban.

Comment: So there is no way to use only `limit_req_zone`? Just blocking access to Basic_Auth index file or passwords file?

Answer (score 1):

You can set some secret cookie header after authorisation. And block only requiress without the "secret cookie"

```
http {

    map $cookie_SECRET_NAME $is_limited{
        default $binary_remote_addr;
        "SECRET_VALUE" "";
    }

    limit_req_zone $is_limited zone=one:10m rate=30r/m; # only one login in 2 seconds allowed
    ...

    location / {
        limit_req zone=one burst=5 nodelay; # only five connections allowed for the whole / root
        ...
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:2222/myapp/www/; # redirections to my unauthenticated service
    }
}
```

In php script you can add the cookie after first success login

```
<?php
setcookie("SECRET_NAME", "SECRET_VALUE");
?>
```